# Kerberos configuration on Sharepoint 2013

Tags: kerberos

I Have Sharepoint 2013 Server with Database on the same machine.

I have configured Kerbereos following the [Youtube Kerberos configuration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Slvtnmom5eE&t=1s)

I have enabled Kerberos in my web application and configured SPN on my DNS server. Also I created a delegation to the service account. However it's not working my site collection is always requesting credentials and it doesn't pass

Comment: There should be kerberos error messages in your windows event log (if it is a kerberos error that is occurring). What are you delegating to? That is a long vid so maybe a summary of what you did.

Comment: In fact I've got error ID 4 and I think I know why in delegation of the service account that I assigned to the SPNs I selected "Trust this user for delegation to specified services only" Our Sharepoint envirenment is under secure network. So I'll try "...Trust any service (Kerberos only)" Thank you for the clue